# Reduction of the standard error in a magnetometry experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

I have to answer this question for my physics lab, but our lab is about the mean, standard deviation, and standard error on the mean, and I see absolutely no connection to this.

Here is the problem:

> "In a magnetometry experiment, after a minute of collecting data the statistical noise was reduced to 1 picotesla. For how much longer should data be collected in order to reduce the random error by a factor of 10?"

Answer (score 0):

Do they give a starting value? The random error is just the statistical noise, meaning if you took a measurement you would get (value) ± 1 pT. They seem to be asking how long it will take for the statistical noise to be .1 pT, so I think you would need to know the error reduction per time interval.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have a starting value or any other info that could help.

Comment: In that case I would use a ratio. Some googling reveals that the formula for standard error is S.E. = σ/√n , where σ is the standard deviation and n is the number of measurements. Taking n = (rate of measurements)*(time) and assuming the rate of measurements is constant, you can set S.E.(1)/S.E(2)=10=(σ1√T2)/(σ2√T1).